# Html not displaying django

Tags: python, django, web

**Views.py:**

```
def index(request):
return HttpResponse(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index1.html"))
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index1.html")),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

File is in the same directory v1.10

Source on chrome:

```
<function TemplateView at 0x00000000034A6E18>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
     return render(request, 'index1.html')
```

inside templates folder create a file named index1.html and write your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects):

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index1.html', {})
```

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox What error do you have in the console? And where do you have your template?

Comment: For the time being i put it in the same directory as the view.py file is in

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox change `'index1.html'` to `'path_to_template.index1.html'`

Comment: `return TemplateResponse(request, '\\polls\\templates\\polls\\index1.html', {})`

Comment: @ChrisEthanFox just `'\\polls\\index1.html'` should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128106/discussion-between-yevhen-kuzmovych-and-chrisethanfox).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the index view. TemplateView does that for you. If you want to use a function view you should use render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index1.html')
```